# C++ Creating a variable sized array from ifstream

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

Just a heads up: My c++ programming skills and terminology is intermediate at best. So please be gentle ;).

I am working on a multi-sort algorithm for a college class. Originally, I built the program to take in an array of 20 integers, since that was as big as the .txt files were. The final lab is now asking to take in files that have 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 and 1000000 different numbers. I originally used an  ifstream inside a for loop to read in the ints. Now that I need to read a variable amount of ints from a file, I have run into issues with this code. I have extensively searched this site and Google to find an answer to this problem. I have tried dozens of different code snippets, to no avail. Here is the code I am currently running that works for 20 ints.

```
int i;
int A[20];
int length;
char unsortedFilename[200];
ifstream unsorted;

cout << "Please type the full name of the file you would like sorted.\n* ";
cin >> unsortedFilename;
unsorted.open(unsortedFilename);

length = (sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A));

for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
    unsorted >> A[i];
    cout << A[i] << "\n";
}

insertionSort();
```

I do have other code mixed in there, but it's error checking, selection of duplicate number removal, etc. I would like it so that code like this would run "i" number of times, where "i" is actually the number of ints in the file. Also, as I mentioned earlier, I will need to input a file that has 1,000,000 numbers in it. I don't believe that an int array will be able to hold that many numbers. Is it going to be as easy as swapping all my ints over to longs?

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: Why don't you use a vector<int> ?

Comment: It's hard for the code to know how many numbers are in the file before reading the whole thing, so you have some choices to make. Has your class dealt with dynamic memory structures (e.g. linked lists)?

Comment: This class that I am taking involves coding with c++ (no c++ pre-req classes), but the course is based on the prinicples of algorithms. Like I mentioned, my c++ skills are pretty basic. Im looking at cplusplus.com for vector<int>, but their page is pretty cryptic to me :(.

Comment: Use string instead of char array for the file name (what if it's more than 199 characters?) and vector and the push_back function to store any number of ints.

Comment: @user2856289 Better refer to this reference: [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: `int a; while (file >> a) { myvec.push_back(a); } for (int i = 0; i < myvec.length(); i++) { cout << myvec[i]; }`

Comment: @Neil Kirk I have extensively tried using a string, but it compiles with errors. The file names won't be longer than 20+ characters (not a big concern, but I realize this is faulty programming).

Comment: Replace `char unsortedFilename[200];` with `string unsortedFilename;` and it should just work. You may need `unsorted.open(unsortedFilename.c_str());` if you have an old compiler.

Comment: If you recommend STL, at least recommend the proper way: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(fin), std::istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(vector))`. But I doubt the scope of the assignment is to teach STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a vector.

try this,

```
int i;
vector<int> A;
int length;
string unsortedFilename;
ifstream unsorted;

cout << "Please type the full name of the file you would like sorted.\n* ";
cin >> unsortedFilename;
unsorted.open(unsortedFilename);

int temp;
for( i = 0; unsorted >> temp; i++ )
{
    A.push_back(temp);
    cout << A[i] << "\n";
}

insertionSort();
```

A vector is basically a dynamic array. It automatically grows as more space is needed. That way it doesn't matter if you have 10, 100, or even 100000 items, it'll automatically grow for you.

Also use a string for your file name, some file names are longer than 200 characters.

Good Luck!

Comment: Unusual use of a for loop.

Comment: Ya, I would use a while, but it looks like he wants to print out each item as he puts it in. Of course there are other ways, like A.back(), but I didn't want to force him to change his loop.

Comment: Much appreciated Jared. I have an issue when trying this code. I think I need to pass A[] into my "void insertionSort()". What is the preferred way to do this with a vector?

Comment: you've probably looked here, but its a great reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Also check out the STD sort using a vector
  std::sort (A.begin(), A.end());

Comment: @user2856289 `myvec.data()` or pre-C++11 `&myvec[0]`

Answer (score 1):

1. As suggested in the comments, use `std::vector<int>` instead of an array.
2. Instead of a `for` loop, use a `while` loop. Break out of the `while` loop when there are no numbers to read.

The `while` loop:

```
std::vector<int> A;
int item;
while ( unsorted >> item )
{
   A.push_back(item);
}
```

You can sort the `std::vector` by using `std::vector::iterator` or simply access the data through the `int*` returned by `A.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read all the numbers into a vector. Then use the vector as you would have used the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string unsortedFilename;
  std::cout << "Please type the full name of the file you would like sorted.\n";
  std::cin >> unsortedFilename;
  std::ifstream is(unsortedFilename);
  std::istream_iterator<int> start(is), end;
  std::vector<int> A(start, end);
  std::cout << "Read " << A.size() << " numbers" << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> will need to input a file that has 1,000,000 numbers in it. I don't believe that an int array will be able to hold that many numbers.

Sure it can. 1 Million ints is ~4Mb of memory, which is a trivial amount. You can even declare it static just as you do now `int A[1000000];`.

But real problem is that you're assuming a fixed length in your code, rather than determine the length from the input. I guess this is what your assignment is trying to teach you, so I won't show you the solution. But consider using `ifstream::eof` and make your sort accept the length as an argument...

Comment: I would NOT consider using `ifstream::eof`